# ISP installation

Tags: networking, server, internet, dns, windows-subsystem-for-linux

As I mentioned before I was trying to install ISP through the instructions of https://projectisp.github.io/ISP_tutorial.github.io/install/#installation-for-windows-users.

I continued until step 6. But at this step, I don't know how to go to   `./isp/installation`. I tried these commands:

```
$ isp/installation
$ cd ./isp/installation, 
$ cd isp/installation, 
$ cd /isp/installation,  
$ cd /./isp/installation
```

but for all I got the same error.
I will appreciate it if you can help me with this problem.

Comment: just run ./isp/installation/ISP_installer.sh and you're ready to go

Comment: Did you run `git clone https://github.com/ProjectISP/ISP.git`? I think you need this. However, you should probably ask the developers of this project why their documentation is so lacking ..

Comment: In the other question, you mention that you are running WSL, but you don't have that tag on either question.  I *highly* recommend tagging WSL-related questions with [tag:windows-subsystem-for-linux] and mentioning that you are using it each time you post.  It's quite different from "normal" Ubuntu.  I've made the changes to the tags for you in this case.  Thanks!

Comment: I didn't know that this tag exists. Thank you for editing. I will follow your tip in future questions.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the documentation for that project is bad to say the least.

*I think* it's expected that before you can install, you have to run the first command in the very top:

```
git clone https://github.com/ProjectISP/ISP.git
```

After that, you would be able to continue with the commands under *"6. Install normally ISP"*.

It would be a help to future user is you told whoever is responsible for this project that their documentation could use some work.

Comment: Thank you so much. I'm following your instruction. I hope it works. Unfortunately, I don't have access to the author.